# How do I mount my local React directory into my React docker container?

Tags: reactjs, docker-compose, dockerfile, mount

I'm trying to build a React 16.13.0 app, running in a Docker container (alongside a Django app).  I would like to mount my local React directory so that my React docker container reads its files from there so that if I change a file on my local file system, it's automatically picked up by my React docker container.  I have this docker-compose.yml file ...

```
version: '3'

services:
...
  client:
    build:
      context: ./client
    volumes:
      - /app/node_modules
      - ./client:/app
    ports:
      - '3001:3000'
    restart: always
    container_name: web-app
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=development
      - REACT_APP_PROXY=http://localhost:9090
    #command: npm run start
    depends_on:
      - web
...
```

This is the Dockerfile file in my React directory (client/Dockerfile) ...

```
FROM node:10-alpine AS alpine

# A directory within the virtualized Docker environment
# Becomes more relevant when using Docker Compose later
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Copies package.json and package-lock.json to Docker environment
COPY package*.json ./

# Installs all node packages
RUN npm install

# Finally runs the application
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

Sadly, this doesn't seem to be working.  Changes to my local file system are not getting reflected in my running Docker container.  What else should I be doing?

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#volumes - you can map path to path

Comment: Hi @xadm, Haven't I done that?  Under volumes I have "- ./client:/app" mapping my local "client" to the "app" directory.

Comment: shouldn't it be `/usr/src/app` ? ... `node_modules` are not mapped

Comment: try portainer - it's far easier to modify/manage docker/images/parameters

Comment: Oh yeah, that path was wrong.  I think that was the root of the problem.  Never heard of portainer but I'll check it out.

Answer (score 0):

Dockerfile seems ok. Here is portion of docker-compose.yml. Note env. variable CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true at the bottom.

```
version: '3.7'

services:

  react:
    container_name: react
    build:
      context: react/
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - './react:/app'
      - '/app/node_modules'
    stdin_open: true
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    environment:
      - CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true
```